# nginx - How to use multiple sub_filter in one location?

Tags: nginx

Nginx config segment:

```
    location / { 
            sub_filter_types text/plain;
            sub_filter hello hi; 
            sub_filter 'hi' 'how are you';
            sub_filter_once off;

            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

Then reload via:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Then get warning:

> nginx: [emerg] "sub_filter" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:46

I saw similar config in [nginx doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html?&_ga=1.80378644.2017320381.1455803440#sub_filter).

**The question is:**

- Why get the warning, can't multiple sub_filter be used together as a chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems similar to https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,259029,259029.
Was your nginx compiled with the nginx_substitutions_filter module?

Also, aren't you missing quotes around the values in this statement?

> sub_filter hello hi;

Comment: But, the nginx doc didn't mention that. I install by `apt-get` on ubuntu. And, the quote is not needed I guess, since there is no space in each part.

Comment: Ah. I see. The quotes was just a curiosity and if that could be the issue. Well the issue seems very similar to Florin Andrei's issue on the nginx mailing list.

Comment: Ok, seems nginx don't support multiple sub_filter as a chain by default.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like support for multiple sub_filter directions in a single location was added in Nginx version 1.9.4.  You may need to upgrade to a more recent version.

> Several sub_filter directives can be specified on one configuration
>   level (1.9.4).

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html